# How to read in text lines containing ^M character in Python?

Tags: python, vim

```
时尚 娱乐明星 设计 家装家居 过节指南圣诞节穿搭^M 圣诞月怎么红红绿绿怎么来
```

I am reading in a text file like above:

```
with open('test.tsv', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:

   for line in f:
      print(f)
```

Due to the ^M character, the line ends at this character, not the whole line. How to read the whole text as one single line instead of multiple lines? I can replace it with a space.

In vim, I tried Ctr+M on my mac to search it, but the search failed. How to either remove it in vim or in python code to replace it with a space?

Comment: It works for me without needing to replace `^M`, make sure you are using `print(line)` instead of `print(f)` though.

Comment: The `^M` is a carriage-return character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below command to get rid of `^M` in vim and to insert `^M` Press **Ctrl+V Ctrl+M**

```
:s/^M$//
```

Instead of removing `^M` if you want to replace `^M` with `newline` use

```
:%s/^M/\r/g
```

For `mac` users use `dos2unix` command

```
dos2unix myfile.txt
```

without using `Ctrl` you can replace `^M` using the below command:

```
:%s/\r$/ /g
```

Comment: How do you type. ^M on Mac?

Comment: @marion, like on any computer.